# How does one algebraically solve the wave equation (PDE)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

My textbook explains how to solve the wave equation:

$$u_{xx}(x,t)=u_{tt}(x,t)$$

It proposes the following solution:

> define the following variables $\zeta, \eta$ and function $v$: 
>   $$\zeta =x+t $$ 
>   $$\eta = x-t$$
>   $$v(\zeta,\eta):=u(x,t)$$
>
> Then it can be derived that  $$u_{xx}=v_{\zeta \zeta}+2v_{\zeta
>  \eta}+v_{\eta \eta}$$ $$u_{tt}=v_{\zeta \zeta}-2v_{\zeta \eta}+v_{\eta
>  \eta}$$
>
> Hence  $$u_{xx}-u_{tt}=4v_{\zeta \eta} \implies v_{\zeta \eta}=0$$
>   Hence we can derive by integrating twice that  $$v(\zeta,
> > \eta)=f(\zeta)+g(\eta)\implies u(x,t) = f(x+t)+g(x-t)$$ for some
>   arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$.

---

**My quesion is:** how could we have derived that in order to solve this, $\zeta$ and $\eta$ must be equal to $x+t$ and $x-t$ respectively? And how do we know that we should use this approach in the first place?

Is there a systematic method to knowing which functions and variables to choose to solve such a PDE, because the method seems very different from the method of characteristics that I have been using for first-order PDE's.

Answer (score 5):

Substitution for mentioned equation comes from physical reasoning (it called wave equation on purpose). For some randomly chosen point on wave front, which propagate with speed $1$ ($1D$-case) $x\pm t$ is constant, sign depends on the direction of propagation. Note that we consider two waves propagating in opposite directions in the environment at the same time.

In many cases suitable substitutions can be deduced from geometrical symmetries. Comprehensive explanation can be found in P. J. Olver, Applications of Lie Groups to Diferential Equations, or similar book.

Comment: So there is no "systematic" way of finding such solutions to PDE's? You basically have to memorize a solution trick for each different type of PDE ?

Comment: @Programmer2134: well, we can't solve all PDE's in the world, however I think that approach of theory of groups can be called systematic, as it virtually can be applied to any equation (desired result not guaranteed though)

Comment: I suppose to get to the point where one understands Lie groups and their application to differential equations would take quite a while, if one starts with only an artificial understanding of groups?

Comment: @Programmer2134: maybe day or two to understand how to use it for concrete equations, while understanding of theoretical side without a doubt takes much more time.

Answer (score 1):

In the present one-dimensional case it is a standard trick based upon:
$$ 0= (\partial_{tt}-c^2\partial_{xx}) u = (\partial_{t}-c\partial_{x}) (\partial_{t}+c\partial_{x}) u $$ This reduces the PDE to a method of characteristics with respect to $\xi = x-ct$ and $\eta=x+ct$ for which the above reduces to:
$$0 =\partial_\xi \partial_\eta u$$
The drawback is that it really only works well in one dimension.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Could you explain why it is justified to "factor" the second order derivatives into first-order ones, the same way we factor quadratic equations? It is not immediately clear to me why this is allowed.

Comment: When $u$ is $C^2$ then the derivatives $\partial_t$ and $\partial_x$ commute: $\partial_t \partial_x=\partial_x \partial_t$. Note that you may use the same method to solve: $ (\partial_{tt}-c^2\partial_{xx}) u = F(t,x)$ (having the so-called d'Alembert solution).

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting there. I am more generally wondering why it is allowed to treat $\delta _x$ and $\delta_y$ as separate from $u$, and perform calculations with them that ignore $u$? are we also allowed to do this with *total derivatives*? It seems somewhat counterintuitive to me, since the derivations of derivatives depend e.g. on whether $u$ is single- or multi-valued . (e.g., $d_x u=\delta _x u$ if $u(x)$, but $d_x u=\delta _x u + \delta _y u$ if $u(x,y)$. It seems to me that it cannot just be assumed that we can treat $\delta _x$ seperately from $u$, but that this has to be proven.

Comment: For example, how do we know that we can write $\delta _t - \delta _x = \delta _{\eta}$ for some $\eta$, without first finding an $\eta$ for which that equation holds?

Comment: I don't quite see what you mean by $d_x$ and $\delta_x$? Given a system of coordinates say, $x,t$ a function $u(x,t)$ has well-defined partial derivatives. When you change coordinates, $\xi=x-ct$, $\eta=x+ct$ then your function in terms of the new coordinates is  $\tilde{u}(\eta,\xi) =u(\frac{\eta+\xi}{2}, \frac{\eta-\xi}{2c})$. You then get relations between partial derivatives, e.g. $\partial_\eta \tilde{u}(\eta,\xi) = \frac12 (\partial_x - \frac{1}{c}\partial_t) u(x,t)$. What is sometimes confusing is that you write $u$ instead of $\tilde{u}$ for the functions in the new coordinates.